How to create Hawkbit update server docker image with extensions for AWS and Azure?
In our application we need hawkbit to store artifacts in AWS S3 or Azure Blobstore - for which I believe we can use hawkbit-extensions. I need to create a Hawkbit update server docker image with extensions to be deployed into the cloud - does Hawkbit provide a update server docker image with extensions? If not, how can I create a custom docker image from the Hawkbit source after adding the extensions dependency in the pom.xml.
`    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.hawkbit</groupId>
        <artifactId>hawkbit-extension-artifact-repository-s3</artifactId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.hawkbit</groupId>
        <artifactId>hawkbit-extension-artifact-repository-azure</artifactId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
    </dependency>
`

I built hawkbit-parent code by adding these dependencies in pom.xml - jars get created in individual projects under hawkbit-parent - how to aggregate this as a docker with extensions?

Did you solve the issue?
